# Why shapely falied to detect if given Geo Coordinate point is in the route

Tags: python, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geometry, shapely

I want to detect if given Geo coordinates fall into the route I will be tracing.
I am using shapely for this but that doesn't seems to be working correcly with Geo Coordinates.
Can you please explain what am I doing wrong here

Using snap_to_road google maps API I snap the route to get multiple GPS points along the route, then I create the LineString(coordinates) from it and used LineString.contains method to check if given point falls in the line

```
>>> from shapely.geometry import *
>>> coords = [(18.541658213425041,73.802487036668737),(18.541715999999997,73.8024635),(18.5417578,73.8024447),(18.5417578,73.8024447),(18.5417748,73.802437),(18.541841700000003,73.8023838),(18.541933099999998,73.8022613),(18.542033699999998,73.8021515),(18.542150000000003,73.802104)]
>>> line = LineString(coords)
>>> line.contains(Point(18.541933099999998,73.8022613))
True
>>> line.contains(Point(18.542077799999994,73.8021211))
False
```

Code to get multiple points across the route:

```
import urllib,json,requests 
request = "https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?path=18.5416582,73.802487|18.5462013,73.8025098|18.5536253,73.80331540000002\
        &interpolate=true&key=<API KEY>"

response = urllib.urlopen(request).read() 
print response
```

As per google maps this (18.542077799999994,73.8021211) point is a part of route these co-ordinates are following.
Then why does shapely failed to detect it ?
Does it has to do something with 2D and 3D geometry.

Edit:
Following two sites will help you to measure buffer value in meteres

http://www.longitudestore.com/how-big-is-one-gps-degree.html
https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/degrees-to-degrees-minutes-seconds.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `buffer` method to dialate little bit. Increase the number `0.01` if you can allow more tolerance.

```
line.buffer(0.01).contains(Point(18.541933099999998,73.8022613))
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. can you please just verify if this is the right approach to do things I am doing.

Comment: `LineString` has area equal `0`. There is floating precision problem in your case, so you just dialte the line to 'Polygon' by using buffer. In this way `contains` problem is solved.

Comment: Somewhat late to the party, but: it is usually faster to use foo.distance(bar) < epsilon rather than foo.buffer(epsilon).contains(bar).